# How to delete my question

Tags: discussion, support, deletion, deleted-questions

I just posted this question on SE: [How to make two vectors orthogonal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276070/how-to-make-two-vectors-orthogonal)

I want to delete it because I have come up with a way to word it better and manipulate it so people can understand what I'm doing, but I can't edit the whole thing as then the comments and answers won't make sense. But I can't delete it because it has answers on it.

What could I do?

Comment: +1: I wish all users were this considerate!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can edit it with a note to say what you're doing, and leaving the original at the bottom so people can connect it with the answers and comments.

Comment: I would only mention for future readers that each individual SE site has their own way of dealing with this sort of thing. So, although this is the right thing to do for a question on math.SE, it might not be appropriate on a different site.